# Normal text is invisible when using beamer with notes and XeLaTeX

Tags: beamer, xetex, presentations

I'm using beamer with xelatex to prepare a talk.

If I switch on notes on right I'm experiencing strange behaviour:

When using csqoutes in the title, all normal text afterwards becomes invisible (or white). The text selectable in the output pdf. Note that the text is also visible in the small preview on the note page.

This does not happen when using pdflatex or lualatex.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{\enquote{Enqouted Title}}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{This is the second slide}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Update:

`csqoutes` is not the culprit. Seems to be a general problem when using `xelatex` and `beamer` with notes enabled.

New MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{First Slide Title}
        Here be text
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{This is the second slide}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is the `note` setting, at first glance. Without `notes`, everything works. You should load `polyglossia` to get german quote style

Comment: And it works with `lualatex`. Strangely enough. If you don't need `xelatex` then use `pdflatex` or `lualatex`

Comment: I'm using system fonts. I figure that is possible using `lualatex`. Do I need to keep something in mind if I switch to `lualatex`?

Comment: I'm already using `polyglossia` in my document. I left it out in the MWE because it was not necessary to reproduce the error.

Comment: It has nothing to do with csquotes. The color is white on the second frame also without it.

Comment: You are right! I was sure I tested without csqoutes and it worked. Will edit the main post.

Comment: related bug report github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/337

Answer (score 20):

The

```
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}
```

trick kinda worked for me, but it totally messed up the position of my images in my presentation. So I decided to dig a little further and here is what I've found :

This is indeed a bug, and depending on the beamer theme you are using, the package *pgfpages* will override the behavior of the theme which is using :

```
\AtBeginSection{...}
```

but there is an easy workaround to set back the font color every time there is a new slide :

```
\makeatletter 
\def\beamer@framenotesbegin{% at beginning of slide
     \usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}
      \gdef\beamer@noteitems{}% 
      \gdef\beamer@notes{}% 
}
\makeatother
```

Using this, you'll be able to set the font color back to theme's default color.

Hope this helps. Cheers !

Comment: Oh man thank you so much! I was going crazy trying to figure this out. I also had a hard time searching to figure out what it was! This works perfectly!

Comment: Life saving, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The following solves the problem in the present example.
However it is not a true solution. I only give this in order
to show where the bugs are. I think the bugs are in
a pgf driver pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def, which is used by XeTeX.

```
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{First Slide Title}
        Here be text
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{This is the second slide}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Official fix available!

This was a bug in the [xetex-def](https://ctan.org/pkg/xetex-def) package and has been fixed by [Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright) in a [recent commit to its development branch](https://github.com/latex3/graphics-def/commit/5a934cb80ff9f9c3014c6891f2bd41a417e57445).

As of 2021-01-20, the change is still pending being released in the [xetex-def package on CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/xetex-def). Hence, simply copy [xetex.def](https://github.com/latex3/graphics-def/blob/develop/xetex.def) into the same folder as your `.tex` document you want to compile.

If you're from the future, you might instead try updating your `xetex-def` package. With MikTeX you can try doing so in the MiKTeX console under "Updates".

Comment: Putting the file in the same folder as the `.tex` file did not solve the problem using `xelatex`

Comment: This solution worked on TeXLive 2021.