# Problems with second beamer slide and displaying notes on second screen with XeLaTeX

Tags: beamer, xetex

I am trying to automatically add a slide to the end of a beamer presentation, but when I show notes on a second screen the text of that added slide does not appear on the slide. Here is a MWE:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtEndDocument{
    \begin{frame}{At End}
        Goodbye.
    \end{frame}
}

\usepackage{pgfpages} % must come after \AtEndDocument{...}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen} % (*)

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{First Slide}
    Hello.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The above latex produces a PDF with the last slide having a title of "At End" but no text (i.e. "Goodbye." does not appear). Oddly, "Goodbye." *does* appear in the small copy of the slide that is displayed on the notes part.

For font reasons I must use xelatex, however this problem disappears when using pdflatex. Also if line (*) is commented out the problem disappears.

How can I make "Goodbye." appear on that last slide?

I am using `XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017/W32TeX)`.

## Update (2018-04-02)

I have realized that this has nothing to do with `\AtEndDocument`. For example, the following seems closer to a true MWE:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen} % Both

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
%\color{black}
Sometimes disappears
\begin{itemize}
    \item an item
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Note that this issue only appears if all of the following conditions are met:

- The document is compiled with xelatex (as opposed to pdflatex)
- Notes are displayed on the second screen
- The text that vanishes is on the second slide or later
- The text that vanishes is at the top level (and not in an `itemize` environment, for example)

As @samcarter points out it seems to be a foreground color issue since explicitly setting the foreground makes the text visible again. I found the following answer solved my problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/306662/1078 (although it is clearly a bandaid).

Comment: Funny, using XeLaTeX I can reproduce your issue, but if I use pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX the last slide is shown correctly (but throws some warnings during compilation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly the colour of the "Goodbye" is white, that's why you don't see it.

Workaround:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtEndDocument{
    \begin{frame}{At End}
        \color{black}Goodbye.
    \end{frame}
}

\usepackage{pgfpages} % must come after \AtEndDocument{...}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen} % (*)

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{First Slide}
    Hello.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's perfect! Do you know why this happens? Is it a XeLaTeX bug, which should be reported?

Comment: @banbh Seems to be related to xelatex, but I have no idea what might cause this problem.

Comment: I added an update explaining that what I thought was a MWE was not! It seems to happen on any slide *after* the first!