# Problem with math in pgfpages and notes in beamer

Tags: beamer, xetex, pgfpages

I am trying to write a presentation in beamer with notes in a separate page. I am using the pgfpages package. When I compile the file only with the slides everything appears to be fine. When I use the option to show notes on the second screen, then any slide with math becomes blank.  Here is an example of what I did,

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}

%\setbeameroption{hide notes} % Only slides
%\setbeameroption{show only notes} % Only notes
%\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right} % Both
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

    \title[CMB]{Παράδειγμα τίτλου}
\author{Γιώργος Παπαδόπουλος}\institute[ΟΚΕ]{Όνομα Πανεπιστημίου}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}\titlepage \note[item]{Χαιρετισμός}\end{frame} 
\begin{frame}{Outline}
    \tableofcontents
\note[item]{Say hello}
\end{frame}

\section{Σχετικότητα -- Κοσμολογία}
\begin{frame}{Einstein}
    \[R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}R g_{\mu\nu}  =   -\frac{8\pi G}{c^4} T_{\mu\nu}.\]
\begin{equation}\label{eq:gr einstein equation}
R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}R g_{\mu\nu}    =   -\frac{8\pi G}{c^4} T_{\mu\nu}.
\end{equation}
  \note[item]{Η βασική ιδέα της γενικής σχετικότητας} 
   \note[item]{Η αρχή της ισοδυναμίας}   
   \note[item]{συναλλοίωτη μορφή} 
   \note[item]{μας λέει οτι υπάρχει ένα σύστημα συντεταγμένων στο οποίο οι σχέσεις ισχύουν, το σύστημα το οποίο είναι τοπικά αδρανειακό στην χωροχρονικό τόπο του
  συστήματος που μελετάμε.}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result is as follows with no notes pages,
[image: Slides only]

And with notes pages,

[image]

Even the text disappears. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Probably using `\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}` as described in the answers to  [Normal text is invisible when using beamer with notes and XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/232168/134144) helps.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/337

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for you fast answers, I thought it was a problem in math and so I did not find these posts. What seems to have fixed the issue is using the link that leandriis posted, [Normal text is invisible when using beamer with notes and XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232168/normal-text-is-invisible-when-using-beamer-with-notes-and-xelatex)

As mentioned in that post, I used the following code just before the frame,

```
    \def\beamer@framenotesbegin{% at beginning of slide
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}
    \gdef\beamer@noteitems{}% 
    \gdef\beamer@notes{}% 
}
\makeatother
```

Slides reappeared.